# Get the real size of a layout (WRAP_CONTENT)

Tags: java, android

I need to get the size of the layout which height set as WRAP_CONTENT.

I tried to get it by calling

> `LinearLayout.getLayoutParams()`

Which returns the height = -1 or -2 ( I know this is due to WRAP/MATCH Content ).

I've also tried

> `LinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight()`

it returns 0.

How could I get the real size of the layout ? Bellow is my sample code.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void loadComponents() {

    showMenuButton = findViewById(R.id.showMenuButton);
    showMenuButton.setOnClickListener( v -> inflateMenu());
    listNote = findViewById(R.id.listNote);

    Point point = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(point);

    LinearLayout thisLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    this.Y = thisLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
    this.offsetY = point.y - Y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = thisLayout.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all notice that if your Linerlayout is not yet drawn both thisLayout.getHeight() and thisLayout.getWidth() will return 0.

So :

```
thisLayout.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       int height = thisLayout.getHeight();
       int weight = thisLayout.getWidth();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code to get size of the layout whenever it changes.

```java
// In you Activity / Fragment

private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener thisLayoutTreeObserver =
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // here you can get updated height of the View
                thisLayout.getHeight();
            }
        };

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    thisLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(thisLayoutTreeObserver);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    thisLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
            .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(thisLayoutTreeObserver);
}
```

[`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver) can be used to get notifications when global events, like layout, happen.

Here is an additional important consideration from the official documentation:

> The returned ViewTreeObserver observer is not guaranteed to remain
> valid for the lifetime of this View. If the caller of this method
> keeps a long-lived reference to ViewTreeObserver, it should always
> check for the return value of `ViewTreeObserver.isAlive()`.